# How to get folder type using Outlook REST API

Tags: outlook, office365, office365api, outlook-restapi, office365-restapi

I'm using Outook REST API v1, and try to get all folders with `https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/me/folders`.
But response I got not has `Folder Type` or something like that, I can use `DisplayName` to know type of folder. But `DisplayName` different when using different language. So, what I wonder, can we decode the folder's ID or something to know type of folder. Can someone help me? Thank you !

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by type? Do you mean what kind of items they hold, or are you looking for something else?

Comment: @JasonJohnston Yes, I want to know kind of items they hold, more details, I want to know, which is Draft folder, Inbox folder, Outbox folder ... . without using `DisplayName`, because `DisplayName` different when using other Outlook language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Nan's answer, we've added a new property on the `/beta` endpoint called `WellKnownName`, which will give you the corresponding well-known URL segment for a folder, assuming it is one of the special folders. For example:

```
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/mailfolders/

{
  "Id": "AQMkADAwATE0YzYwLWU2YWQtMzI2MS0wMAItMDAKAC4AAAPlai60KwU4RaQaBohCjrEVAQDChncDEyhVQLMhyjJAPQSqAAACAQwAAAA=",
  "DisplayName": "Inbox",
  "ParentFolderId": "AQMkADAwATE0YzYwLWU2YWQtMzI2MS0wMAItMDAKAC4AAAPlai60KwU4RaQaBohCjrEVAQDChncDEyhVQLMhyjJAPQSqAAACAQgAAAA=",
  "ChildFolderCount": 0,
  "UnreadItemCount": 39,
  "TotalItemCount": 8174,
  "WellKnownName": "inbox"
},
{
  "Id": "AQMkADAwATE0YzYwLWU2YWQtMzI2MS0wMAItMDAKAC4AAAPlai60KwU4RaQaBohCjrEVAQDChncDEyhVQLMhyjJAPQSqAAACAT4AAAA=",
  "DisplayName": "Jobs",
  "ParentFolderId": "AQMkADAwATE0YzYwLWU2YWQtMzI2MS0wMAItMDAKAC4AAAPlai60KwU4RaQaBohCjrEVAQDChncDEyhVQLMhyjJAPQSqAAACAQgAAAA=",
  "ChildFolderCount": 0,
  "UnreadItemCount": 0,
  "TotalItemCount": 6,
  "WellKnownName": null
}
```

The first folder above is the Inbox (`WellKnownName` = `inbox`), and the second folder is a user-created folder (`WellKnownName` = `null`).

Comment: Thank you ! I think you guys should add this attribute soon or ember into folder id.

Comment: Yes, it will move out of beta to one of the production endpoints, probably 2.0.

Comment: and since that was 4 years ago, the real answer is probably never

Answer (score 1):

Yes, after changing timezone/language in mailbox settings ,the DisplayName of the original mailboxes(such as Inbox,Drafts..) will also be changed , but  you can use the following well-known names to access the corresponding folder: Inbox, Drafts, SentItems, DeletedItems. For example :

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/me/folders/Drafts
```

above GET request will get the resources of the Drafts .

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks bro. Some my customers have special folder name, ex : Send Messages, Deleted Messages... I don't know why did they have them. Now I don't have their accounts, so can't test will folders/SendItems and folders/SendMessages are one.